# Getting CPF9DEC error when calling Qc3EncryptData

Tags: rpgle

I'm getting the CPF9DEC (Cryptographic service provider not valid) error when calling Qc3EncryptData to encrypt data using triple DES.  I'm passing in the value of '0' for this 'Cryptographic service provider' parameter (parameter 8).  According to the IBM doc (see link below), value of '0' means any CSP (The system will choose an appropriate CSP to perform the encryption operation).  Any idea how I can get pass this error?

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/qc3encdt.htm#algd0200

Below is the strip down version of my code:

```
  * algorithm DS                                       
 D ALGD0200...                                         
 D                 DS                  qualified       
 D  algorithm                    10i 0 inz(21)         
 D  algorithmBlockLen...                               
 D                               10i 0 inz(8)          
 D  mode                          1    inz('1')        
 D  padOption                     1    inz('2')        
 D  padChar                       1    inz(x'00')      
 D  reserved                      1    inz(x'00')      
 D  MACLen                       10i 0 inz(0)          
 D  keySize                      10i 0 inz(0)          
 D  inzVector                    32    inz('myvector') 
                                                       
  * key DS                                             
 D KEYD0200...                                         
 D                 DS                  qualified       
 D  keyType                      10i 0 inz(21)         
 D  keyLen                       10i 0 inz(24)         
 D  keyFormat                     1    inz('0')                        
 D  reserved                      3    inz(*allx'00')                  
 D  key                          32    inz('123456789012345678901234') 
                                                                       
  * error DS                                                           
 D reffldIBMErrorDS...                                                 
 D                 DS                  qualified template              
 D  totalLen                     10I 0 Inz(%Size(reffldIBMErrorDS))    
 D  resultLen                    10I 0 inz(0)                          
 D  msgID                         7A                                   
 D  reserved                      1A   inz(x'00')                      
 D  msgDta                      256A                                   
                                                                       
  * ibm encrypt api                                                    
 D Qc3EncryptData  PR                  extProc('Qc3DecryptData')       
 D  piClearData               65535A   options(*varsize) const         
 D  piClearDataLen...                                                  
 D                               10I 0 const                           
 D  piClearDataFormatName...                                           
 D                                8    const                    
                                                                
 D  piAlgorithm                  64A   const options(*varsize)  
 D  piAlgorithmFormat...                                        
 D                                8A   const                    
                                                                
 D  piKeyDesc                   512A   const options(*varsize)  
 D  piKeyFormat                   8A   const                    
 D  piCryptoServiceProvider...                                  
 D                                1A   Const                    
 D  piCryptoDeviceName...                                       
 D                               10A   Const options(*omit)     
 D  piEncData                 65535A   options(*varsize)        
 D  piEncDataSize                10I 0 const                    
 D  piEncDataLen                 10I 0                          
 D  piApiErrorDS                       likeds(reffldIBMErrorDS) 
 D                                     options(*varsize)        
                                                                
 D myClearData     s           3000    inz('Hello World')       
 D myEncData       s          65535A                            
 D myEncDataLen    s             10I 0                          
 D myIBMApiErr     ds                  likeDS(reffldIBMErrorDS) 
 D                                     inz(*likeds)             
                                                                
  /free                                                         
                                                                
                                                                
     // encrypt the data                                        
     Qc3EncryptData(myClearData  :%len(%trimr(myClearData))     
                   :'DATA0100'                                  
                   :ALGD0200         :'ALGD0200'                
                   :KEYD0200         :'KEYD0200'                
                   :'0'              :' '                       
                   :myEncData        :%size(myEncData)          
                   :myEncDataLen     :myIBMApiErr               
                   );                                           
                                                                
    *inlr = *on;                                                

  /end-free
```

Comment: show your code, including the prototype being used.

Comment: Added a strip down version of my code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my prototype, I have the extproc as Qc3DecryptData.  It should be Qc3EncryptData

D Qc3EncryptData  PR                  extProc('Qc3DecryptData')